# Factory or Strategy pattern to use?

Tags: php, oop

I can not decide what pattern to use in case when I have incoming data as string:

```
$form = "formRegistration";
```

Based on this I need to return a certain template HTML.

In simple case it looks as:

```
if ($form == "formRegistration") {
   echo include("formRegistration.php");
}
```

I'm confused which pattern to use: Factory or Strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

It just a basic templating engine. For more info, read this old article: http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

The design patterns are **not solutions**. They are shorthand descriptions of the code that has already been written. Developers use patterns to quickly communicate to other people the intent and general shape of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Factory pattern, as the name suggests is used to produce objects. In your code, more than producing something, you are performing a particular action, so this should be the case of strategy pattern, as you perform an action depending of what you have in input.

Comment: Can you share a simple example of strategy for my case? When I have interfce